# Heterogeneous arguments in a Scala function

Tags: list, scala, shapeless, heterogeneous, hlist

How can I pass some `HList` as an argument? So I can make in a such way:

```
def HFunc[F, S, T](hlist: F :: S :: T :: HNil) {
    // here is some code
}

HFunc(HList(1, true, "String")) // it works perfect
```

But if I have a long list, and I dunno nothing about it, how can I make some operations on it? 
How can I pass argument and not to loose its type?

Comment: What sort of operations do you want to perform in the method body?

Comment: hm, some type dependent objects can be stored in this list, and I want not to lose information about object types. So I need mb all operations on `HLists` - `map, head, etc...` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your use-case.

`HList` is useful for type-level code, so you should pass to your method not only `HList`, but also all necessary information like this:

```
def hFunc[L <: HList](hlist: L)(implicit h1: Helper1[L], h2: Helper2[L]) {
    // here is some code
}
```

For instance if you want to `reverse`  your `Hlist` and `map` over result you should use `Mapper` and `Reverse` like this:

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.ops.hlist.{Reverse, Mapper}

object negate extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int]{i => -i}
  implicit def caseBool = at[Boolean]{b => !b}
  implicit def caseString = at[String]{s => "not " + s}
}

def hFunc[L <: HList, Rev <: HList](hlist: L)(
                              implicit rev: Reverse[L]{ type Out = Rev },
                                       map: Mapper[negate.type, Rev]): map.Out =
  map(rev(hlist)) // or hlist.reverse.map(negate)
```

Usage:

```
hFunc(HList(1, true, "String"))
//String :: Boolean :: Int :: HNil = not String :: false :: -1 :: HNil
```

Comment: y, I see, for example: `def hFunc[L <: HList](hlist: L)(implicit m: TypeTag[L])` and there is all information about object type in `m`; but I can't make `hlist.head`, cause in fact `hlist` argument has another type; and it throws an error (on making `hlist.head`): `could not find implicit value for parameter c: shapeless.IsHCons[L]`

Comment: @DaunnC: Not `TypeTag`. You should use `Mapper` for `map`, `Reverse` for `reverse` and so on.

Comment: @DaunnC: I guess [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) source, example and tests are best learning resources. You could also read stackoverflow [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapeless?sort=votes&pageSize=50). I don't know other useful links. See update in my answer for code example.